# How to connect to SQL Server from client?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

Which should be selected?

```
Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

or

```
Data Source=190.190.200.100;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Comment: If the one without the port works, why do you consider that it might be better to specify the (default) port ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends - if your SQL Server runs on absolutely everything with their default settings, then you don't need to specify neither the port, nor the protocol to use.

Just use:

```
Data Source=190.190.200.100;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

That should be enough.

If your server has custom settings, e.g. uses a custom port - then you must add that to your connection string, of course.

For a great many samples and explanations, see [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com)

PS: I personally would use

```
Server=190.190.200.100;Database=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

since I find `Server` and `Database` much clearer and more obvious than `Data Source` and `Initial Catalog` - from a functionality point of view, those two connection strings are identical (for SQL Server)